# Spring hibernate non column model variable

Tags: spring, hibernate

In spring and hibernate I have a vehicle model. Now vehicles can have proposals on them and I want a variable in the vehicle model to represent the total proposals that have been made. I want it to be a variable as I serialize it and output it as JSON. Someone has suggested that instead of doing this I should do a seperate AJAX request to pull the total proposals for a vehicle. The issue is if I am listing a vehicle on a mobile application I will get like 30 ajax requests for one list. It does not make sense to me it makes sense to append the total proposals to the vehicle model.

Does anyone have any advice on which way to go about this? If you agree with storing it in the vehicle model even though it is not a column in the database can you give the best way to go about this thank you
Dan

Comment: I should also mention I have a proposals table that holds a vehicle_id so many proposals for a vehicle. I just wish to hold the total proposals in the vehicle model rather than using a column to represent this.

Comment: Don't put that information in the entity. Put it in a DTO class that models what you want to send to the browser. The entity models what there is in the database row for that vehicle. The two are related, but different.